# Adding Column to Master View

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I currently have a drill down master detail report. I would like to include extra information in the master to sort by that isn't included in the master table.

```
Example:
Master: Employee ID, Position
Detail: Employee Name
Third Table: Hire Date
```

Is there a way to include hire date as a column in the master view so that users can sort by it?

Comment: That third table had best have more columns than "Hire Date"

Comment: @JNevill there is a lot more data than what is shown. The data I provided for the example is dummy tables as I cannot share my actual data. Thanks!